# python subprocess "no such file or directory" inside docker

Tags: python, docker, centos

app.py

```
    def which(program):
        import os
        def is_exe(fpath):
            return os.path.isfile(fpath) and os.access(fpath, os.X_OK)

        fpath, fname = os.path.split(program)
        if fpath:
            if is_exe(program):
                return program
        else:
            for path in os.environ["PATH"].split(os.pathsep):
                exe_file = os.path.join(path, program)
                if is_exe(exe_file):
                    return exe_file
        return None

    command = /some/path/to/command
    command = which(command)
    if command is not None:
        print "command exists and is exectuable"
        child = subprocess.Popen(command)
```

OUTPUT:

```
command exists and is exectuable
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

when this is run inside docker, even though it could find the executalbe, when it's run via subprocess, it is throwing the "no such file" error

when this is run outside of container, i dont see this behavior

any advice on what's going on here when the command is run via subprocess? when I added shell=True, it still cant find it

Comment: Did you build your image on Ubuntu?

Comment: @aerokite centos

Comment: `ls -la /some/path/to/command` ?

Comment: I have seen this problem before. May be you do not have permission to run that command, or that command is not executable.

Comment: but isnt which() make sure that it is executable and that i can run it? and now im getting /bin/sh: 1: ls: not found

Comment: inastall `bash`. and it should work. I have faced this problem in alpine.

Comment: bash is already installed. /bin/bash: 1: ls: not found. how does shell works inside docker?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164394/discussion-between-aerokite-and-ealeon).

Comment: i had to run it via /bin/ls and shell=False

Comment: which centos are you using? I don't see problem with ls

Comment: @aerokite not sure exact version. i used the line FROM centos. any are you running from python subprocess.Popen("ls", shell=True)

Comment: worked too. Checked it now

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue also. I had `script_1` with hashbang `#!/usr/bin/env python3` which called `Popen(['script_2'])` which had hashbang `#!/bin/env python3`. Popen() was reporting `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/path/to/script_2': '/path/to/script_2'`, but actually the problem that `/bin/env` didn't exist. I corrected script_2's hashbang to use `/usr/bin/env` to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was trying to build a Golang executable from Alpine base image and I was trying to copy and execute it on python:3.9-slim base image. I was getting FileNoteFound error even though file existed with executable mod.

It was happening because program was compiled for one environment and was used in another env.

Following solution worked for me.

I required to build my executable for linux by setting the GOOS environment variable.

For instance, to install a go binary like:

```
RUN go install github.com/google/osv-scanner/cmd/osv-scanner@v1
```

It should be done like this:

```
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 GO111MODULE=on \
    go install github.com/google/osv-scanner/cmd/osv-scanner@v1
```